# How can I setup this structure without corrupting my stack?

Tags: c

I need to setup the following structures and print out the content of the addr-array.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8                   len;
    uint8                   ch;
    uint8                   cmd;
} ATTR_PACKED
RESPONSE_R;

typedef struct
{
    RESPONSE_R          rspr;
    uint8               addr[SIZEOF_ADDR];
} ATTR_PACKED
RESPONSE_ADDR;
```

However, my current solution is corrupting my stack around the variable `rspr`. As far as I know, it is because `addr` is an array and I am setting it up wrong. But I am not sure if so and why. On the debugger it looks ok, until I get the error-message, while exiting the function.

```
//this code has to be ansi-c
void    OnResponse(uint8 *pPkt){

RESPONSE_R rspr;
//pPkt[0] holds the lenght of the received response, which equals to sizeof(rspadr)
//before this was ok, but I guess, now it is not, because RESPONSE_R stores just the
//pointer, not the whole array
memcpy(&rspr,pPkt,pPkt[0]-sizeof(rspr));            

switch(rspr.cmd){
 case CMD_READ_ADDR:
   RESPONSE_ADDR rspadr;
   memcpy(&rspadr,pPkt,pPkt[0]);
   //nevermind the cout, this is for debug only     
   cout << "ADDR: " << endl;                
   printf("%02x",rspadr.addr[0]);
   break;
 default:
   break;
 }
}
```

`rspadr` gets the right data, so why am I corrupting my stack with this code?

*Edit*

`memcpy` uses `pPkt` to determine the size, because `pPkt[0]` holds the size of the transmitted response-bytes. But maybe there is a point here, and I should change that to directly use the structure size. However - it is not the main problem here.

The main troublemaker is, how do I convert my data from the `pPkt[]` buffer into my structures, when one of these structures has an array, like RESPONSE_ADDR has?

raw-view of the `pPkt[128]` array

```
[0x0] = 0x09
[0x1] = 0x00
[0x2] = 0x02
[0x3] = 0x00
[0x4] = 0x16
[0x5] = 0x01
[0x6] = 0x02
[0x7] = 0x03
[0x8] = 0x04

[0xa] = 0x00
[0xb] = 0x00
[0xc] = 0x00
...
[0x127] = 0x00
```

This above is the input I get. Now, I need to setup an `RESPONSE_R` object, in order to select a rountine determined by the `cmd` section (represented by pPkt[2]) and an `RESPONSE_ADDR` object in order to get the address, which would be `001601020304`.

I would very much like to be able to use something like `rsp.cmd` and `rspadr.addr[0]`.

Comment: Why are your memcpy()s getting size from pPkt[0] rather than using the size of the target structure?

Comment: Where does the `pPkt` point to? What is its size?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey would you mind explaining, why you changed the tag to [c++]? which part of my code is clearly a [c++]-only feature? I would like to know, because I am trying to avoid [c++] in this code, that is why it was tagged [c]

Comment: @Jook I'm guessing cout.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - oh, yeah, thanks for the hint, but this there just for debug purposes.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to write C using a C++ compiler. I can think of quite a few examples of ANSI C code that wouldn't be valid as C++.

Comment: yeah, but I have to right now. It is somewhat a dual-development. While creating something in windows, some parts are going to be used in a C-Only environment.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - why is my problem too localized? I have already tried to make this somewhat a universal question. Setting up a structure, which includes an array, with the use of a buffer - at least that seemed not to be such a localized problem.

Comment: @Jook I haven't voted this as too localized.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - sorry, I was not implying, just wondering. Becasue of your experience, I hoped you could enlighten me on this subject, as I tend to have this issuse repeadetly.

Comment: @Jook It was the cout.  Surprising use of it since you printf() straight after, why not printf("ADDR:\n%02x", rspadr.addr[0]);

Comment: @SpacedMonkey - because I currently code like a mad cow, using whatever works to get it done :) however, I corrected this after the mixup here and currently am using your suggested line ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
memcpy(&rspr,pPkt,pPkt[0]-sizeof(rspr));
```

The 3rd argument of `memcpy` is the number of bytes to copy, which can't exceed the size of `RESPONSE_R`.

Did you mean

```
memcpy(&rspr,pPkt,sizeof(rspr));
```

?

**Update 2**

How about this solution, which doesn't require any `memcpy`?

```
const RESPONSE_R* p_rspr = (const RESPONSE_R*)pPkt;

switch(p_rspr->cmd){
 case CMD_READ_ADDR:
   const uint8* addr = pPkt+sizeof(RESPONSE_R);
   //nevermind the cout, this is for debug only     
   cout << "ADDR: " << endl;    
   for (uint i = 0; i != p_rspr->len; ++i)            
     printf("%02x", addr[i]);
   break;
 default:
   break;
 }
```

Comment: you pointed out the error - +1 - but could you provide a solution too? i've edited some explanaiton into my code.

Comment: @Jook: I still don't completely understand the format of the input, but I added a solution which you could use as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough, I think we misunderstood. See my latest edit. I don't need an array of `RESPONSE_R` - I need to setup the values (len,ch,cmd) for a single `RESPONSE_R` and `RESPONSE_ADDR` object (rsp,addr). And the problem is this `addr`-value

Comment: I am really grateful for your efforts! Your last solution basically works, I modified it a bit, using this line: `const RESPONSE_ADDR* p_rspadr = (const RESPONSE_ADDR*)pPkt;` instead of `unit8* addr`. This seems quite neat. Would you mind adding some explainations to this magic line? Because I fear it creates only a pointer to a part of `pPkt`. What happens when I flush `pPkt`?

Comment: `p_rspadr` is just a pointer to `pPkt` and it gets flushed with it. For now this is ok, but if you should know how, would you tell me how to solve this with a real copy of the `pPkt` data?

Comment: ok, after I checked again: using `memcpy(&rspr,pPkt,sizeof(rspr)); ` fixes my old code AND you gave me a new way to solve this - THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Can you recheck the below statement.

```
RESPONSE_R rspr;
memcpy(&rspr,pPkt,pPkt[0]-sizeof(rspr));
```

Looks like you are trying to copy in an incorrect way.